# How to make Mineflayer (Minecraft Bot) click a block like Sign

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft

I'm trying to make a Minecraft bot, called Mineflayer, click a block, which in this case is "Sign Block". I'm unable to deal with Vec3 in this case as well. In short: How could I make the bot click the sign block.

I have already tried referring to Mineflayer's official documentation but it is not at all explained. I also tried asking some people using Mineflayer, but none of those could help me as well.
Below is the code, and the error I'm facing.

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const Vec3 = require('vec3');

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 25564,
  username: 'Minecharmer',
  version: '1.12.2'
})

let blockAt = (x, y, z) => blockAt(new Vec3(x, y, z));
let blockAtVec3 = (v) => bot.blockAt(v);
let blockClick = (x, y, z, callback) => {
     bot.activateBlock(blockAt(x, y, z), callback);
}

bot.on('chat', (username, message) => {
  if (username == 'Username' && message == 'clickblock') {
    startClicking();
  }
})

function startClicking() {
  blockClick(-74, 65, 254, () => {
      console.log('Clicked block!')
      startClicking();
  });
}
```

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: This `let blockAt = (x, y, z) => blockAt(new Vec3(x, y, z));` looks like infinite loop. You are calling same function over and over again. Maybe it should be `bot.blockAt(...` ??? Same loop will happen with startClicking function.

Comment: @Molda Thank you so much! You are like god to me! Great! Thanks for helping me out! I get silly sometimes and sorry for taking your time. But once again, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score -1):

Add a delay to your startClicking function.